# Randomly Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

How to change this code avoid using python for-loop, but numpy function

```py
h, w = 2, 2
im = np.random.randint(255, size=(h, w, 3))
index = np.random.randint(3, size=(h, w))
number = np.random.randint(255, size=(h, w))
for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        im[i, j, index[i, j]] += number[i, j]
```

Comment: What you're doing is creating a h * w array with three layers, filling it with random numbers and then adding to values on a random layers for each position in the array. What exactly are you looking to replace here? Are you wondering if there is some numpy-specific way of updating those values on random indices for the entire array? If so, why? What's wrong with a for loop in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an example as small as yours you will be having a hard time speeding up the loopy code. `numpy` pays for the overhead it incurs only from a certain problem size upwards:

[image]

The plot shows execution time of original loopy code (`OP`) vs vectorized code (`pp`) over total number of pixels `w x h`.

It was generated using:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import face

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def OP(im,index,number):
    im = im.copy()
    h,w,_ = im.shape
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            im[i, j, index[i, j]] += number[i, j]
    return im

@B.add_function()
def pp(im,index,number):
    im = im.copy()
    h,w,_ = im.shape
    h,w = np.ogrid[:h,:w]
    im[h,w,index] += number
    return im

@B.add_arguments('#pixels')
def argument_provider():
    im = face()
    h,w,_ = im.shape
    mh,mw = h//2,w//2
    for exp in range(-8,1):
        fr = 2.**exp
        dh,dw = int(fr*mh),int(fr*mw)
        index = np.random.randint(3, size=(2*dh, 2*dw))
        number = np.random.randint(255, size=(2*dh, 2*dw),dtype=im.dtype)
        yield 4*dh*dw,MultiArgument([im[mh-dh:mh+dh,mw-dw:mw+dw],index,number])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('randomchannel.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does the same as your original code, but avoids using `for` loops. Why you'd want to do this is unclear however, since I would consider this solution decidedly worse than the original.

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

h, w = 20, 20
im = np.random.randint(255, size=(h, w, 3))


def increase_random(x):
    result = np.copy(x)
    result[np.random.randint(3)] += np.random.randint(255)
    return result


def loops():
    index = np.random.randint(3, size=(h, w))
    number = np.random.randint(255, size=(h, w))
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            im[i, j, index[i, j]] += number[i, j]


def vectorized():
    irv(im)


irv = np.vectorize(increase_random, signature='(n)->(n)')

print(timeit(vectorized, number=10))
print(timeit(loops, number=10))
```

I've added some time measurements to show that, in this case, vectorization does nothing to improve performance. On my machine, the `loops` code is about 25x faster.

However, if the operation you're performing is simpler or complex but easier to optimize, it would likely benefit from vectorization. It just so happens that your example is not very likely to benefit from it, while the loop is fairly small and efficient.

Comment: Isnt that for-loop is very slow compare to numpy ?

Comment: Not really, although it really depends on the type of operation you're performing. So, when I say 'not really', I mean 'not in this particular case' - in general though, vectorizing tends to be a great improvement. So, if your example was just that, an example, then yes, vectorizing should be faster. I'll add some timings to the answer for comparison.

Comment: thanks a lot, nice explanation for measuring performance between them

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not 'true' numpy veectorization.  It does not speed things, especially not the signature version.

Comment: Agreed, which is also why the help text for the function specifies "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." - but not quite as efficient as the actual for loop as it turns out.